# PIC16f877: MPLAB X error 1250 (Could not find space for variable)

Tags: pic, mplabx, xc8

I am using Pic16f877 microcontroller for my project. I am trying to declare a char Array as

```
char dataPkt[256] = {0};
```

While compiling, i received an error

```
error: (1250) could not find space (256 bytes) for variable dataPkt
```

Can anyone guide me how to resolve this error ??

Comment: That device only has 368 bytes of RAM and you are trying to reserve 256 of them. I suspect you have other variable declarations too? You need to live within your budget ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland, thanks for your comments. I tried with 100. And I m not using enough variables too.Than too the error remains the same. Can you guide me alternate way to overcome the issue ?

Comment: If you look at [page 13 of the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30292D.pdf), you'll see that there are multiple banks of memory. For your array, you need contiguous bytes in a single bank. The largest bank is 96 bytes. The others are 80 bytes. There's little chance of finding the space you need in a single bank.

Comment: RTFM! - - - - -

Comment: @Roger: There's actually as many as 112 bytes available consecutively (110h-17Fh, inclusive)... who knows if the compiler is smart enough to treat it as a single block when needed.... and of course the multimapped region is usually too valuable to waste like that.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok, I missed the other 16 but I think the OP gets the point now, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no substitute for understanding the machine at the low level.  Whether using a compiler or not, you have to actually **READ THE DATASHEET**.

As Figure 2-3 on page 13 clearly shows, there is no way to get 256 contiguous bytes of RAM.

Other observations:

MPLABX is the IDE, so is useless in specifying what compiler or assembler you are using.

Allocating a buffer for a whole packet sounds like big-processor thinking on little processors.  There is no OS with canned drivers that is going to read/write whole packets from/to some communication interface.  Ultimately, code is going to handle each byte separately anyway.  Buffering a packet of bytes, then reading and handling them out of the packet individually anyway makes little sense.

Comment: thanks for your reply. What if I use pointer instead of array ?? There is no compile error. Will it also have bytes limitation ???

Comment: @skg: A array and a pointer are two completely different things.  You need to learn some basics of programming and what a machine does under the hood before continuing.

Comment: @skg, I think it's best for you to look into the "Understanding Small Microcontrollers" book (available online for free).

Comment: "big-processor thinking" This is exactly the issue.  +1